# web3 throwing error when converting number to BN

Tags: web3js

I am trying to write an approval function, which approves spender to spend some amount of tokens. I am getting an error relevant to the amount of tokens I am entering. I have tried several ways of entering the token amount, but each one is giving me the same error. Token I am approving has 18 decimals. The part of the code responsible looks like this:

```
async function setAllowance() {
  try {
    const amount = 1000;
    const tokens = web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), "ether");
    const bntokens = web3.utils.toBN(tokens);

    const data = await tokenContract.methods
      .approve(SPENDER_ADDRESS, bntokens)
      .encodeABI();

    const gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
      to: TOKEN_ADDRESS,
      data,
    });

    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

    await tokenContract.methods
      .approve(SPENDER_ADDRESS, bntokens)
      .send({
        from: WALLET_ADDRESS,
        gas,
        gasPrice: Number(gasPrice) * 1.1,
        data,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

The error I am getting always looks like this:
`Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "248559080000.00003" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "248559080000.00003"`

I have no clue what I am doing wrong and I would appreaciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: The error message says it, decimals are not supported, and your number is a decimal

Comment: @JulissaDC The token amount is not decimal though, it's 1000 which is a normal int. When I log the number, it's 1000000000000000000000.

Comment: does it work with `1000000000000000000000` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using `web3.eth.sendTransaction(my data here)` instead of `contract.methods.approve().send()`. I am not sure what caused this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I just send the numbers encapsulated in `BigInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

binary doesnt have decimal points. so what binary is essentially is just a different way of counting, we use base 10 where we have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0. numbers, binary is base 2, which only counts using two numbers 1,0.

so if i want to reach a number like 345 in binary i would count it out as 0011011001

basically what i am doing here is i am assigning place value for every number here.
to visualize this ill explain every place and its value in base 10

```
 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
128|64 |32 | 16| 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
```

so in this case

```
00001000 = 8

00001100 = 12

00100001 = 33
```

and thats how you count in binary, that should give you all the knowledge you need to understand the problem.